# How to disable prepared statement in heroku with postgres database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I fixed an issue on my rails project locally (with postgres config) while adding in database.yml this statement:

```
test:
  prepared_statements: false
```

The bug that I fixed was related to this issue:

```
 PG::ProtocolViolation: ERROR: bind message supplies 2 parameters, but prepared            statement "a24" requires 1
```

Now, I want to fix it on my production app hosted on Heroku with a postgres database. I don't know how to disable prepared statement as the database.yml is automatically generated. I tried to append:

```
/database?prepared_statements=false
```

to my database's URI but it ends up with a DATABSE_URL that is wrong and so I can't connect to my database.

What is the process and the right syntax to disable prepared_statement?

Comment: You more "worked around" the issue than actually fixed it. If there's a real bug in ActiveRecord, the Pg gem, etc, it'd be nice to have a self-contained test case to demonstrate it. (Can't really help you apply the workaround on Heroku, haven't used its app hosting much).

Answer (score 17):

As of Feb 19th 2014, heroku [no longer overrides `database.yml`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/426) so you can turn off prepared statements in your `production` and `staging` (or `default`) block of the `database.yml` file as recommended by the [latest docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/postgres-logs-errors#rails-4):

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5
  prepared_statements: false

development:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp_test

production:
  <<: *default
  url:  <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
  pool: <%= ENV['DB_POOL'] || ENV['MAX_THREADS'] || 5 %>

staging:
  <<: *default
  url:  <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
  pool: <%= ENV['DB_POOL'] || ENV['MAX_THREADS'] || 5 %>
```

Comment: This set `prepared_statements` to false correctly for me. You can run `ActiveRecord::Base.configurations[Rails.env]` in `rails console` to verify it.

Comment: Link to heroku article on how to disable prepared statements as successfully described in markquezada's answer: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/postgres-logs-errors#out-of-memory-errors

Answer (score 7):

We were worried about brittleness and maintaining consistency between staging/production (using DATABASE_URL on Heroku) and development/test (using database.yml/database.example.yml).

Inspired by [Rails' tests](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/08754f12e65a9ec79633a605e986d0f1ffa4b251/activerecord/test/support/connection_helper.rb), we put this in config/initializers/disable_prepared_statements.rb:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  ActiveRecord::Base.remove_connection.merge(
    :prepared_statements => false
  )
)
```

`remove_connection` returns a hash of the connection parameters of the connection being removed. This should let any database.yml or DATABASE_URL continue working.

Comment: This doesn't work for me: ActiveRecord::Base.configurations does not contain prepared_statements => false

Answer (score 3):

You should just be able to add `?prepared_statements=false` to the existing database url and restart your dynos. This worked for us.

```
heroku config:add DATABASE_URL=[old database url here]?prepared_statements=false
```

To check that it's set after restarting your server you can open a console and query `ActiveRecord::Base.connection_config`.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass in a configuration hash to ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection, in an initializer. For example:

```
configure :production, :development, :test do
  db = URI.parse(ENV['DATABASE_URL']

  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
      :adapter => db.scheme == 'postgres' ? 'postgresql' : db.scheme,
      :host                => db.host,
      :username            => db.user,
      :password            => db.password,
      :database            => db.path[1..-1],
      :encoding            => 'utf8',
      :prepared_statements => false,
  )
end
```

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/establish_connection/class

Answer (score 1):

Recently it seems that Heroku has disabled setting DATABASE_URL using `heroku config:set DATABASE_URL=<blah>?prepared_statements=false`, giving us back an error " ▸    Cannot overwrite attachment values DATABASE_URL."

In order to resolve this, we added an disabled_prepared_statements.rb initializer in config/ containing:

`ActiveRecord::Base.configurations[Rails.env].merge!(prepared_statements: false)`

Answer (score -4):

turning off prepared statements decreases performance because postgresql has to replan every query before executing so i do not suggest to turn it off for production servers - especially as rails is notorious for doing many small queries when you don't take really good care about eager loading everything. I suggest indead figuring out how to do restarts in live after each deployment without affecting the availability of your service. I am not a rails guru but i know that it's doable (our company does it exactly like that). Here is a bit more insight into why this is happening https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/12330

Comment: That issue means such

Comment: @kristok Can you offer any advice on how to do gradual deploys without running into issues with prepared statements? I don't see anything in that issue offering a solution aside from disabling them. Saying it's possible and not giving any insight isn't very helpful.

Comment: @lobati there is no easy solution to this, thats why it has not been offered. The generic thing to google for is "rails zero downtime deployment" basically everybody is building their own complicated procedures to overcome the shortcomings of rails.

Comment: @kristok the google results for "rails zero downtime deployment" tend to tackle how to keep your database and code compatible across two versions of code. I don't see anything that tackles how to cope with active record issues with prepared statements. I do see some stuff recommending disabling it so that the database can be scaled with pg_bouncer.

Comment: @lobati and as long as rails migrations are as broken as they are that is the way to go unless you intend to dig deep and fix it. The worst i've seen during the 9 months i wrote rails was that the migration that had been solid for 4 years suddenly broke one day on developer boxes because rails changed the DDL generation logic between versions. After that there was really no way to have a reproducable live structure based on existing migrations so we just hacked something into migrations to have dev environments resemble live. So my best answer would be to follow those code compatibility rules