# How can I prevent any ActiveRecord::PreparedStatementCacheExpired errors immediately after running `rake db:migrate`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, transactions, database-migration

I am working on a Rails 5.x application, and I use Postgres as my database.

I often run `rake db:migrate` on my production servers. Sometimes the migration will add a new column to the database, and this causes some controller actions to crash with the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::PreparedStatementCacheExpired: ERROR: cached plan must not change result type
```

This is happening in a critical controller action that needs to have zero downtime, so I need to find a way to prevent this crash from ever happening.

Should I catch the `ActiveRecord::PreparedStatementCacheExpired` error and retry the `save`? Or should I add some locking to this particular controller action, so that I don't start serving any new requests while a database migration is running?

What would be the best way to prevent this crash from ever happening again?

Comment: I usually rescue the error and retry the save since the ActiveRecord::PreparedStatementCacheExpired actually clears the cache on error. The second save attempt should then work.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to fix this issue in some places by using this `retry_on_expired_cache` helper:

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true

  class << self
    # Retry automatically on ActiveRecord::PreparedStatementCacheExpired.
    # (Do not use this for transactions with side-effects unless it is acceptable
    # for these side-effects to occasionally happen twice.)
    def retry_on_expired_cache(*_args)
      retried ||= false
      yield
    rescue ActiveRecord::PreparedStatementCacheExpired
      raise if retried

      retried = true
      retry
    end
  end
end
```

I would use it like this:

```
  MyModel.retry_on_expired_cache do
    @my_model.save
  end
```

Unfortunately this was like playing "whack-a-mole", because this crash just kept happening all over my application during my rolling deploys (I'm not able to restart all the Rails processes at the same time.)

I finally learned that I can turn off prepared_statements to completely avoid this issue. (See [this other question and answers on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22813750/how-to-disable-prepared-statement-in-heroku-with-postgres-database).)

I was worried about the performance penalty, but I found many reports from people who had set `prepared_statements: false`, and they hadn't noticed any problems. e.g. https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=7264171

I created a file at `config/initializers/disable_prepared_statements.rb`:

```
db_configuration = ActiveRecord::Base.configurations[Rails.env]
db_configuration.merge!('prepared_statements' => false)
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(db_configuration)
```

This allows me to continue setting the database configuration from the `DATABASE_URL` env variable, and `'prepared_statements' => false` will be injected into the configuration.

This completely solves the `ActiveRecord::PreparedStatementCacheExpired` errors and makes it much easier to achieve high-availability for my service while still being able to modify the database.

Answer (score 1):

This is solved in Rails 7 by this pull request where an option was added to prepared statements to enumerate the columns when generating those sql statements instead of using table_name.*:

https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/41718

There is no fix  for Rails 6.1 and down. Only Rails 7.

Also, this only fixes it if you are *adding* columns. If you are removing columns then you will want to add the column to ignored_columns in the first deploy of your app like this:

```
class Student < ApplicationRecord
  self.ignored_columns = [:my_column_name]
end
```

And then in the next deploy you can drop the column.